Формирование цен по номенклатуры с учетом производителя
Есть ли возможность в 1С написать свою функцию для формирования цены номенклатуры, которая будет учитывать значение производителя конкретной номенклатуры?
Пример:
если производитель = "Рога и Копыта"
тогда [Акционная цена]*0.75
иначе [Интернет цена]
конецесли


Какая у вас конфигурация?

УНФ. Платформа 8.3.8.2054

При создании вида цены можно попробовать указать тип:

Динамический (формула) - можно будет оформить её через конструктор и проверить
Произвольный запрос - можно указать схему компоновки данных (СКД)
Расширение - позволяет подключать расширения конфигурации и рассчитывать цены, используя любые данные из вашей информационной базы 1С.

Информация взята отсюда - 1С:ИТС. Виды цен, способы расчета и округления

Спасибо, но в моей конфигурации нет Произвольного запроса и Расширения. Только Статический, Динамический (Процент), Динамический (Формула).
И подписки на ИТС тоже нет)
